# Atmel AVR Disassembler

Tags: microcontroller, avr, disassembly, atmel

Can somebody suggest me any disassembler for Atmel AVR 8-bit microcontrollers? There are opensource projects for this?

Thanx.

Comment: The answer was already made almost 6 years before this question `avr-objdump.exe -j .sec1 -d -m avr5 dumpfile.hex`, I tested it today because I'm working on atmega328p reverse engineering. [Information source here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/158180#comment-158180)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[plug]IDA Pro supports AVR disassembly[/plug]:

[image: IDA Pro AVR disassembly]

As for opensource, [AVR GCC](http://www.avrfreaks.net/wiki/index.php/Documentation:AVR_GCC) package includes a port of objdump, including disassembling functionality.

Comment: You can get IDA PRO for the affordable price of $1879 USD, I think it's better to stick with the [open source solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60824029/2188550)

Answer (score 19):

You can also use avr-objdump, a tool part of the avr-gcc toolset ( http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/ ). Ex:

```
avr-objdump -s -m <avr architecture> .d program.hex > program.dump
```

where `<avr architecture>` is found on http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/using_tools.html

Comment: The command that worked for me was:  `avr-objdump -s -m avr5 test.hex`

Comment: Hey @DavidGrayson Do you still use this program? What command is used today? I can't find a ``avr-objdump`` file to execute.

Comment: avr-objdump is part of binutils and should be available in any distribution of GCC for AVR.  I would give you more specifics but you didn't say your OS.

Comment: These days it seems like `-s` does not give you disassembly; you have to use `-D` instead.  Also, the AVR architecture argument depends on what chip you are disassembling for, and you might need to look at `config/avr/avr-mcus.def` in the GCC source code to figure out what the architecture of your AVR is.

Comment: For those on newer Ubuntu (22+), to install this toolset do `sudo apt install gcc-avr`

Answer (score 6):

http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/

Lots of platforms (AVR also) but Microchip (which you didn't need either) is missing.

Big plus is that it is web based.

Comment: Seems long on promise, short on delivery. AVR25 is garbage. Disassembly should match listing file operations.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout [vAVRdisasm](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Disassemblers/vAVRdisasm-28478.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

[AVRDisassembler](https://github.com/christophediericx/AVRDisassembler) is an open source (MIT) AVR / Arduino disassembler written in .NET Core (which means it can run on Windows, Mac, Linux). Apart from writing the disassembly to stdout, it can also emit a JSON dump (for interopability, analysis purposes).

*Disclaimer: I am the author of said library.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [avrdisas](https://www.johannes-bauer.com/mcus/avrdisas/) by Johannes Bauer. It works with dumped flash, rather than the .hex file or ELF.

Compiling the following :

```
  .include "tn13def.inc"
       ldi     r16,1
       out     ddrb,r16      ; PB0 as output
       sbiw    r24,1         ; slight wait
       brne    PC-1
       sbi     pinb,pinb0    ; toggle
       rjmp    PC-3          ; forever
```

produces listing:

```
C:000000 e001             ldi     r16,1
C:000001 bb07             out     ddrb,r16      ; PB0 as output
C:000002 9701             sbiw    r24,1         ; slight wait
C:000003 f7f1             brne    PC-1
C:000004 9ab0             sbi     pinb,pinb0    ; toggle
C:000005 cffc             rjmp    PC-3          ; forever
```

extracting the flash contents with:

```
$ avrdude -p t13 -P usb -c usbtiny -U flash:r:flash.bin:r
```

gives: `e001 bb07 9701 f7f1 9ab0 cffc`

disassembly:

```
$ ./avrdisas -a1 -o1 -s1 flash.bin 
; Disassembly of flash.bin (avr-gcc style)

.text
main:
   0:   01 e0           ldi     r16, 0x01       ; 1
   2:   07 bb           out     0x17, r16       ; 23

; Referenced from offset 0x06 by brne
; Referenced from offset 0x0a by rjmp
Label1:
   4:   01 97           sbiw    r24, 0x01       ; 1
   6:   f1 f7           brne    Label1
   8:   b0 9a           sbi     0x16, 0         ; 0x01 = 1
   a:   fc cf           rjmp    Label1
```

and this works for me, even if the endian-ness does not match the listing and I would need to resolve 0x17 back to DDRB etc.

Answer (score 0):

As opensource disassembler I've tried Radare2 which is command-line oriented but you can also use the GUI called Cutter. https://rada.re/n/

Or you can just use the classical avr-objdump:

```
avr-objdump.exe -j .sec1 -d -m avr5 dumpfile.hex
```

[Information source here](https://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/158180#comment-158180)

Answer (score -2):

The question is rather about disassembling the HEX file and as a solution there  are mentioned quite a lot tools  above in other answers. Hard to add something more.

But if someone is looking for: it is also possible to disassemble the C/C++ while running in IDE. With Atmel studio with its integrated disassembling tool it can be done following way:

1. Run project (it can be run in simulator without debugger hardware);
2. Pause or stop at breakpoint;
3. Press CTRL + ALT + D

This can be useful in order to verify that particular code fragments are compiled as needed because the optimization sometimes skips/mangles the sequence and leads to some unexpected behavior.